# event handler for disruptor not set up correctly

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I am looking to use disruptor 2.10.4.  The disruptor/ringbuffer are attributes within a user defined class.  For some reason, it does not appear to me that my handler is being invoked

```
    final EventHandler<Message> handler = new EventHandler<Message>() { 
        public void onEvent(final UserDefinedMessage event, final long sequence, final boolean endOfBatch) throws Exception {
            log.info("Sequence: " + sequence);
            log.info("disruptor message: " + event.getValue());
        }
    };  

//    disruptor = new Disruptor<UserDefinedMessage>(UserDefinedMessage.EVENT_FACTORY, 1024, exec);  
      disruptor = new Disruptor<UserDefinedMessage>(UserDefinedMessage.EVENT_FACTORY, exec, new SingleThreadedClaimStrategy(50), new SleepingWaitStrategy());
    disruptor.handleEventsWith(handler); 
    ringBuffer = disruptor.start();
```

Update: Pilot error - I do not believe messages are being published to the ring buffer.

Comment: Where's your code publishing to the ring buffer ?

Comment: thanks for commenting - the code publishing to the ring buffer was not getting invoked - pilot error!